# Word Macro to Deselect a content control after macro

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

My current project is making a list for a coworker and since I like to over-complicate everything, I'm running macros for him to check off as he completes work. The description of work will change from a header style to normal when he's completed it, then update the ToC. All of this is working, but I have trouble with the content control staying selected sometimes. I can usually check and uncheck it once or twice with no problem, but eventually the cursor doesn't move out of the check box for some reason so subsequent clicks don't fire the `OnEnter`.

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnEnter(ByVal CCtrl As ContentControl)
With CCtrl
  If .Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then
    If .Checked = True Then
      .Range.Paragraphs.First.Style = wdStyleNormal
      ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Update
      Selection.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    Else
      .Range.Paragraphs.First.Style = wdStyleHeading2
      ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Update
      Selection.MoveRight 1
    End If
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

Is there a way to force word to deselect the content control and move the cursor somewhere on the same line?

I tried `Selection.MoveDown 1`, `Selection.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd`, and also `Selection.MoveEnd` but none work.

Comment: `CCtrl.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Characters.Last.Select`, for example. Then maybe `Selection.Collapse`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Good! I'll write it up as an answer, then, since others could find it interesting. Since you're relatively new to the site:  You know about confirming Answers on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the fact that, through the Content Control's Range the objects which contain it can be accessed. For example, you can "drill up" to the paragraph in which the content control is located:

```
CCtrl.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Characters.Last.Select
```

This could also be any character in the paragraph. The following (in my test) puts the selection immediately after the content control:

```
CCtrl.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Characters(4).Select
```

Incorporated into your code:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnEnter(ByVal CCtrl As ContentControl)
  With CCtrl
    If .Type = wdContentControlCheckBox Then
      If .Checked = True Then
        .Range.Paragraphs.First.Style = wdStyleNormal
        ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Update
        Selection.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
      Else
        .Range.Paragraphs.First.Style = wdStyleHeading2
        ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Update
        Selection.MoveRight 1
      End If

      'Select the last character in the paragraph (the paragraph mark)
      CCtrl.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Characters.Last.Select
      'Remove the selection, so the cursor blinks at the end of the paragraph
      Selection.Collapse

    End If
  End With
End Sub
```